# What language/framework do you recommnend me for implementing a CMS solution?

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

Heyy guys, i have one short question:

What programming language/framework do you think is more suitable for fast and good implementing a CMS solution (for generating websites, eventually on cloud)?

i must actually re write a CMS written in PHP (it is rather old, not written using classes, etc). I would consider Symphony, what do you think?

Comment: I'd suggest to stick with PHP, all other languages are either not so effective for web development or have very steep learning curve. If you go with PHP, I'd recommend Symfony2. There are lot of changes in comparison with Symfony1 that one'd have to adapt to, so that it is a good time to jump in. All people I know that are using Symfony are very effective and successful in what they do and I haven't heard any complains... If you don't want to be a programmer after 4-5 years, go with PHP, if you considering to be one for decade(s), go for Python, Java, RoR, C#. That's how I see it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weell, this is indeed quite open-ended, but i feel that any language having a decent support for web based applications will be a good choice. Your primary concerns w/ a CMS system will be related to caching, persistence modelling, mime type support, internationalization, authoring, authorisation, etc. IMHO, you can go ahead and work w/ any of Python, Java, RoR, C#. I'm not too sure of PHP's support for internationalization, hence i didn't include it in this list.

Drupal is an excellent CMS developed using Py. Alfresco is developed using Java. So the choice is really yours to make - which language are you really comfortable with?

Other than that, when developing a CMS system, it will be really useful for you to take a look at the Content Management Inter-operability Services [CMIS] [specs][1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html). It really helps you to understand the kind of operations and data models you might need to work w/ in a CMS system.

Comment: Drupal is developed in PHP - http://drupal.org/gophp5

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to write an open-source CMS and you want it used by a large share of the community, go for a ubiquitous language that's offered by most hosting services companies: PHP. In the case of frameworks, you have a lot to choose from - depending on your programming skills and resources available on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Why implement from scratch?

CMSs can be big and complex beasts, depending on required features.

There are many CMS products out there, free and proprietary. Why not choose one of those?

---

If you must implement one yourself, I would add that just about any modern language can be used and will have supporting libraries and frameworks to help.

Go with what you know - languages/platforms, but if you are doing this as a learning experience, choose an unknown, so you can learn from it.

Comment: it is already implemented in PHP, but not written using classes. I have to re write it, and make it more secure, and scalable.

Comment: @dana - my answer stands. If you must use PHP, edit your question and clarify this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a weird question because there is not a right answer but my answer may be outside your box. I think perpetuating the same school of thought based on older paradigms is not going to cut it for the future of CMS. You are setting out to support one language and having it installed on the same server as the website consuming it. This is just the same old thing again and again. These days REST and HTML 5 allow a CMS to be plugged into any website. That is a powerful model. I've seen some CMS tools like Page Lime and Simple CMS kind of do that but they fall short using FTP as you can't work with that as a developer since FTP modifies source and if you are doing a dynamic website, no dice. I've also seen Cloud Feed which gets the feed part right then fails short on having you login through their website and do the same old boring editing. Then there is KitGUI which seems to get it right.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is the best option.

Download site: [http://wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org)